# Does Instagram return HTTP 500 response due to rate limiting and/or some form of request filtering?

Tags: instagram, internal-server-error

I'm developing a tool for checking the integrity of links in a web page.

I've noticed that various Instagram URLs will return a HTTP 500 response in cases where if one were to visit the given URL in a browser one would get a HTTP 200 response accompanied by the expected resource.

This is when requesting regular Instagram URLs as one would do as a browser user and not when using the REST API.

A typical request/response using cURL:

```
curl -v http://instagram.com/p/YKTkxHBA-P/
* About to connect() to instagram.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.225.159.246... connected
> GET /p/YKTkxHBA-P/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: instagram.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Tue, 15 Oct 2013 08:31:09 GMT
< Server: nginx
< Content-Length: 87
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host instagram.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

I did for some time get HTTP 200 responses in such cases but am now consistently getting HTTP 500 responses.

This is all specific to a given host; such URLs, even when sending requests with cURL, will return HTTP 200 responses from other machines.

Due to this being specific to the host sending the requests I suspect a form of rate limiting or request filtering by IP is going on, however I can find no documentation to the effect.

Will Instagram officially return a HTTP 500 response as above due to a given IP being denied access?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is it what you (we) are supposing? Aka when your IP gets "banned" you get 500s?

Comment: @kitsched Yes, I'm assuming that a banned IP gets HTTP 500 responses. That's the only conclusion I can come to with the information I have available to me. I admit the information I have may well be incomplete.

Comment: Same here, about the suppositions, I mean. I submitted a request / question to them, asking for my IP to be unbanned. I'm curious if anything will happen. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JonCram Same problem here. Did you find the real reason of this error? I can reproduce this error on individual server. All API requests work fine on other servers. It looks like a ban from Instagram, but they didn't notify about the ban. And sometimes I'm able to make successful request to Instagram API, but it works very rarely...

Comment: I am now suddenly getting this also. It appears it may be an error on Instagram's side now.  I find it odd that it works in my web browser but not on my server though. Using the same URL.

Comment: I also am receiving the 500 on an individual server, but not another one. Works in the web browser with the same URL.

Comment: I also have the same issue with the code 500! Has anyone got a solution or status of Instagram API?

Comment: I have submitted a bug report and received a brief response stating they are looking into it. If you are experiencing this issue, I would submit a detailed message (curl outputs, affected IPs) as well through the official channel so that the platform devs will have a better idea of who is affected and hopefully how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Same problem here. It's not always 500, sometimes the API works as expected and it returns a valid result, but about 70% of time its 500 being returned. I could imagine that the ip is banned, but maybe the information is not distributed to all servers which they have for load balancing. :-/ I also submitted a bug report, no answer yet. @Mark: any luck at your side?

Comment: @ivicaa No :-/ the problem persists, and we haven't heard anything further from Instagram.

Comment: For the record: my 500 Return codes are constant since yesterday. No API call to Instagram is working anymore. Always 500. Instagram support is not responding. :-(

Comment: @Mark Where did you report this issue? Did you receive any news from Instagram? They don't answer me anywhere... That's weird. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelM.Kalygin I used the "Report Issue" button at http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Answer (score 0):

This is an IP rate limit. If you want to skip the part where you contact Instagram and wait for the monkey crew they have working over there to fix the problem, simply assign 1000 IPs to your server and loop through them randomly for your requests. You won't see anymore 500's.

Cheers.

Comment: Lots of people start getting these 500's when you're testing API integration. Because you're most likely requesting the same Instagram page data over and over again during testing, Instagram thinks its a bot and promotes the IP address, this is where you start to see 1/10th of your requests being accepted. I stand behind my given answer, it is the easiest way around this issue, as their API is a pile of sh*t with no real support that is ready and willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've received a mail from Instagram support just yesterday.

> ...
>   Hi, 
>   We made some changes to our server configurations, can you please check if you are still seeing the 500 errors? 
>   Thanks,
>   ...

..well I was 100% certain that those 500ers didn't come from IG's IP rate limit because they weren't returned beforehand either.

I've been checking the logfiles and found a couple 502 (Bad Gateway) and "host unreachables", though no more 500 per se, after **2014-04-14 18:28:56 (PST)**.

Looks like they've finally sorted it out after nearly a month... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem - unfortunately there is no way around it. This happens because of two many requests. At first I thought it was my IP or possibly my UDID until I signed into my app from my own phone and from my home IP but using a **different Instagram** id and it finally worked as expected again. Eventually, I could use my own ID again as time went by but with limited requests. I am not exactly sure how the algorithm works but the more time that went on the more requests I could use again.

Also, this is in real-time on an actual iPhone in an actual app - not on the iOS sim or Instagram API console, FYI.

**Main Point: The request limit is based off the user (5000 requests per hour per user)...there is no IP rate limit.**

Hope this helps :)

Clayton

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. As i've rad, you have to get an extra access to API, I mean the Sandbox mode in your application does not allow you to use all the API. To get extra premissions go to client preferences, tab "premissions".

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be related to curl version, I also experience the same problem with v 7.22.0 on 4 different machines 10 different ip's, while  v7.30.0 and v7.19.7 are working like a charm. 
Currently investigating further more.

Answer (score -2):

I'm almost 100% sure this happens because the domain/IP address is blocked from the Instagram API.

Reason:

1. Works to get the JSON in the browser. Doesn't work to get with cURL from webservice.
2. I copied my exact application from my primary domain (were the application doesn't work) to another domain. Same application worked.

The strange thing is that you get a "500 Internal Error" back and not a message "Your IP is blocked".

Comment: But how to explain that sometimes the request is working from the same ip and sometimes not. Moreover, what is the exact criteria for banning?? :-/